# Need help evaluating a surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

We are looking to find

$\iint_S \mathbf F \bullet  d\mathbf S$  where $\mathbf F$ $=$ $\langle 0 , y , -z \rangle$ and our surface $\mathbf S$ is the paraboloid $y = x^2 + z^2$  for $0 \le y \le 1$ and the disk $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ , $y

First i parameterized our first surface, $\mathbf S_1$ , $y = x^2 + z^2$ for $0 \le y \le 1$

Using polar coordinates we get

$y=r^2$ , $x=rcos(\theta)$ , $z=rsin(\theta)$

Then our parameterization as a vector function is

$\mathbf a(r,\theta)= \langle rcos(\theta) , r^2 , rsin(\theta) \rangle$

Then we find the normal vector function by taking the cross product between $\mathbf a_r$ and $\mathbf a_\theta$

$\mathbf a_r \mathbf \times \mathbf a_\theta = \langle -2r^2cos(\theta) , r , -2r^2sin(\theta) \rangle$

and we have that

$\mathbf F(\mathbf a) = \langle 0 , r^2, -rsin(\theta) \rangle$

thus

$\mathbf F(\mathbf a) \bullet (\mathbf a_r \mathbf \times \mathbf a_\theta) = r^3 + 2r^3sin^2(\theta)$

Thus the flux over $\mathbf S_1$ is

$\iint \mathbf S_1 (r^3+r^3sin^2(\theta)) d\mathbf A$ for $0 \le r \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2(pi)$

which i evaluated to $\frac {5(pi)}{4}$

However the the flux of $\mathbf F$ over $\mathbf S_1$ is incorrect, so my question is where did i go wrong? is the parameterization correct?

Comment: Looks like you could use the divergence theorem since $div(\mathbf F)=0$

Comment: @Loobear23 I noticed aswell but this excersise is done without the use of the divergence theorem. As far as the parameterization for the surface $\mathbf S_1$ goes, is it correct?

Comment: Look at your $F(a)$, the second component should be $r^2$, what is the correct answer? and also a factor of $2$ on $r^3\sin^2\theta$

Comment: The answer is 0. As for accounting for the factor part i still get $\frac{(pi)}{2}$ as the flux for $\mathbf S_1$ instead of it being 0 since the flux for $\mathbf S_2$ is 0

Comment: First the integral you have at the bottom as written would evaluate to $3\pi/4$, not $5\pi/4$. Second, you are missing a factor of $2$ on the $\sin^2\theta$ term, making the integral $4\pi/4 = \pi$. Lastly, check your normal vector. Do you have the correct orientation?

Comment: $<-2r^2cos(\theta) , r , -2r^2sin(\theta)>$ Since the y component is positive that means we have positive orientation which is an outward one

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are right the flux for $\mathbf S_1$ is pi and the flux for $\mathbf S_2$ is -(pi), however i do have a question regarding the normal vector for $S_2$ which is why i was getting this problem wrong i thought it was $<0,r,0>$ since we want positive orientation (outward) and the vectors stick out of the disk, but the right normal was $<0,-r,0>$. Doesnt the normals essentially point "into" the surface, hence negative orientation?

Comment: No you have it completely backwards. Draw your volume and think about which direction $+y$ points for $S_1$

Comment: The normals for $\mathbf S_1$ are perpendicular to the y axis and for $\mathbf S_2$ the normals are parallel